# getTitleTooltip method is not getting called once we mouse over in an Eclipse Editor

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a RCP application where I implemented an Editor by following way-

```
public class CheckView extends EditorPart implements IMessageView,IViewPart {
```

Now I override the method `getTitleToolTip()` method and did some operation which will give different tooltips on different conditions. But the problem is , only once the getTooltip method is getting called , when we launch the RCP tool. But it should always get called whenever we mouseover the editor.
Whats going wrong here?

Comment: You mix up the base classes a little above: `EditorPart` goes with `IEditorPart` and `ViewPart` goes with `IViewPart`. @Baz answer is correct in both cases.

Comment: @bunta Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No .. as I found there is as well a bug raised in Eclipse ... regarding the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documantation of [`IWorkbenchPart#getTitleToolTip()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPart.html#getTitleToolTip()) is quite specific:

> Returns the title tool tip text of this workbench part. An empty string result indicates no tool tip. **If this value changes the part must fire a property listener event with `PROP_TITLE`**.
>
> The tool tip text is used to populate the title bar of this part's visual container.